# Solving a puzzle in prolog - generating a solution with constraints?

Tags: prolog, clpfd

I'm using prolog to try to solve a kakuro puzzle. I have a list of rules like this, where R and C represent the row and starting point of each box, L represents the length and S is the sum of the numbers in the row,

```
 % across(R, C, L, S)
 across(2,4,2,4).
 across(2,10,2,4).  
 across(3,4,4,12).
 across(3,10,2,6).
 across(4,3,2,6).
```

As far  as I can tell, to solve the puzzle across using constraints, for each element L, I would have to find distinct numbers between 1 and 9 which when added up are equal to S. I'm really struggling to work this out, the code I have so far is this:

```
solveAcross(Solution) :-
    findall([R,C,L,S], across(R,C,L,S), List), 
    Solution = length(List, L),
    Solution ins 1..9,
    all_distinct(Solution),
    labeling([], Solution).
```

But all this does is return false.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do `Solution = length(List, L)` and `Solution = 1..9` mean?

Comment: Consider just the conjunction of the two goals `Solution = length(List, L)` and `Solution = 1..9`, which **both** occur in your program. Obviously, this conjunction alone will already **fail**, because `1..9` and `length(List, L)` do not unify.

Comment: @lurker, sorry that was supposed to be Solution ins 1..9, meaning that the generated solutions must be between 1 and 9.
Solution = length(List, L) I thought would make an empty list of length L but typing this out, that doesn't really seem to be what I want to be doing to achieve my goal anyway.

Comment: `Solution = length(List, L)` unifies the term `length(List, L)` with the variable `Solution`. In prolog, you don't "assign" results of a predicate using `=` like you do in other languages. If you want a list of length `L` and the name of the list is to be `Solution`, then you just do, `length(Solution, L)`. If you want `Solution` to have the same length as `List`, you do, `length(List, Len), length(Solution, Len)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first you need to create your matrix, which will end up being the grid of your kakuro puzzle. That is definitely the first step - apologies if you've already made it.

Then you want to make a few rules for the across constraints:

```
acrossConstraints(Matrix) :- getAcross(List), applyAcross(Matrix,List).
%this is the overall thing to call, containing two predicates you need to make
getAcross :- findall([R,C,L,S],across(R,C,L,S),List).
%creates a list of the across facts
applyAcross(Matrix,[[R,C,L,S]|T]) :- acrossConstraints(R,C,L,S,M), applyAcross(Matrix,T). 
%call another rule and recurse over the list.
```

acrossConstraints is the tricky bit - here you want to grab the square you want and then make a list starting from that point. Hint: use append and hint.

Good luck!